# Accessing Javascript variable from another file inside HTML input tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to write a variable from my javascript document test.js, inside my HTML input tag's value attribute. I have this  at the top of my document and want to write the test variable inside an input tag. How can I accomplish this?

test.html

```
<input type="text" id="my_var" value= document.write(test)> <!--I tried this but have had no luck, want to write inside value. -->
```

test.js

```
var test = "hello world";
```

Comment: I don't think you can execute JS code in HTML without such framework. If you use Angular.js for example, then you can. There are other MV* frameworks that can also complete this task, but a pure HTML cannot execute JS code from the inside of an element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript you can find your element in various ways. [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) is a function that (like the name suggests) finds your html element by the id attribute. In javascript you can set the value of your html element like this:

test.html

```
<input type="text" id="my_var" value="">
```

test.js

```
var test = "hello world";
document.getElementById('my_var').value = test;
```

---

I can also recommend [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) if you want to do more html-element manipulations. jQuery is very easy if you know a little CSS, you can select element with the same way, with jQuery you can manipulate the HTML instead of the style. It would look something like this:

test.html

```
<script src="path-to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="path-to/test.js"></script>
....
<input type="text" id="my_var" value="">
```

test.js

```
var test = "hello world";
jQuery('#my_var').val( test );
```

Comment: I was able to get it with jQuery. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="text" id="my_var" value= document.write(test)>
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("my_var").value=test;</s
```